# Common Plot Legends for Density Plot

Tags: plotting, color

In a specified `ColorFunction` such as `SunsetColors`, how can I change the color values for a `DensityPlot` such that I get the sunset color for the negative values only, black for $0$, and purple color for the positive values?  My function is $b = e^{-n x^2 - y^2} + n Sin[y]$. I have to make several density plots against $x$ and $y$ by taking different values of $n$. Each time I change $n$, my `PlotLegends` change. Is there a way to have a common `PlotLegend` for the following three plots? Thank you.

```
b = Exp[-n x^2 - y^2] + n Sin[y];
b0 = b /. n -> 0;
DensityPlot[b0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
b1 = b /. n -> 1;
DensityPlot[b1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
b2 = b /. n -> 2;
DensityPlot[b2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

b = Exp[-n x^2 - y^2] + n Sin[y];
```

The range of the common legend is

```
{min, max} =
 #[{b, 0 <= n <= 2, -4 <= x <= 4, -4 <= y <= 4}, {n, x, y}] & /@
   {NMinValue, NMaxValue} // Rationalize

(* {-2, 2} *)
```

The common color function is

```
cf[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {Purple, x > 0},
    {Black, x == 0},
    {ColorData["SunsetColors"][-x/2], x < 0}}];

Legended[
 Column[DensityPlot[b /. n -> #, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
     PlotPoints -> 100,
     MaxRecursion -> 5,
     ColorFunction -> cf,
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     PlotLabel -> StringForm["n = ``", #]] & /@
   Range[0, 2]],
 BarLegend[{cf, {min, max}},
  LegendMarkerSize -> 500]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, for `n` varying on reals

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[b /. n -> nv, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {min, max}}]],
 {{nv, 1, n}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to have a unified color scale is to set [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) to `False`, and implement a custom scaling for the color function. For this, we can use [`ColorData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) to get the underlying color function, and [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) to do the rescaling:

```
cf = ColorData["SunsetColors"][Rescale[#, {2, -3}]] &;

b[n_] := Exp[-n x^2 - y^2] + n Sin[y];
DensityPlot[b[0], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
DensityPlot[b[1], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
DensityPlot[b[2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]